# how to update table with multiplication function?

Tags: sql, sql-server

when i tried update my table with this query

```
update sekolah set [rata-rata] = 
(select ([total siswa]*12) from sekolah
where [class]='7IPA' and month([Date]) = 08) 
where [class]='7IPA' and month([Date]) = 08
```

a message is :

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

**update**
my table is sekolah

my field is :

class
month
total siswa
rata-rata

Comment: It says `Class` table has more than one record for this filter `[class]='7IPA' and month([Date]) = 08`

Comment: Add some sample table data, both versions before and after the update.

Comment: Can you say what is the common column between sekolah and class tables?

Comment: sekolah and class is same tables

Comment: sorry my fault, my table is sekolah
my field is class, total siswa, and date

Comment: And what about rata-rata ?

Comment: sorry i forget it, rata-rata is my field too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both are same table then it will be helpful:

```
UPDATE s SET s.rata-rata = (s.[total siswa]*12)
FROM sekolah s
where s.class='7IPA' and month(s.Date) = 08
```

OR

```
UPDATE sekolah SET 
rata-rata = ([total siswa]*12) WHERE class='7IPA' and month(Date) = 08
```

Comment: thanks @suraz i have tried your solution, but i found message "Invalid object name 'class'."

Comment: and i tried to change "class c" with "sekolah c" but the result is the same all

Comment: @gufran if you have only one table sekolah and updating rata_rata column please try with updated one above.

Answer (score 1):

The error reason is obvious. Meaning, the nested query is fetching more than one row and Update statement is seeking only one value.

Two solutions

1. Use SELECT TOP 1 statement to in the nested sql to fetch single value.
2. Remove the duplicates from Class table.

   ```
   update sekolah set [rata-rata] = 
   (select TOP 1 ([total siswa]*12) from class where [class]='7IPA' and     month([Date]) = 08) 
   where [class]='7IPA' and month([Date]) = 08
   ```

Comment: Can you post me 1. error message 2. Output of the nested query select TOP 1 ([total siswa]*12) from class where [class]='7IPA' and     month([Date]) = 08

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE sekolah t1 JOIN sekolah t2
    ON t1.class= '71PA' AND t2.month = '08'
   SET t1.rata-rata=(t1.[total siswa]*12)

Comment: Syntax looks like `MySQL`, OP asked for `SQL-Server`